# Systemctl Servies dont see sudo file

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, systemctl

My Problem- i need systemctl servies use sudo, but i dont know why, it doesnot see a sudo file
What i've done wrong?

```
Description=Just_Work_Pls
After=network.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStart=/home/Butter_Manager/sudo /home/Butter_Manager/env/bin/python3.8 manager.py
ExecReload=/home/Butter_Manager/sudo /home/Butter_Manager/env/bin/python3.8 manager.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/Butter_Manager/
KillMode=process
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

in status i see this:

```
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/Butter_Manager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-08-28 18:30:51 UTC; 149ms ago
 Process: 6518 ExecStart=/home/Butter_Manager/sudo /home/Butter_Manager/env/bin/python3.8 manager.py (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Main PID: 6518 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 28 18:30:51 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Stopped Just_Work_Pls.
Aug 28 18:30:51 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Started Just_Work_Pls.
Aug 28 18:30:51 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Butter_Manager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 28 18:30:51 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Butter_Manager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

In logs i see this:

```
Aug 28 18:31:22 Butter-Manager systemd[6623]: Butter_Manager.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/Butter_Manager/sudo: No such file or directory
Aug 28 18:31:22 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Butter_Manager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 28 18:31:22 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Butter_Manager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 28 18:31:28 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Butter_Manager.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 28 18:31:28 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Butter_Manager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 575.
Aug 28 18:31:28 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Stopped Just_Work_Pls.
Aug 28 18:31:28 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Started Just_Work_Pls.
Aug 28 18:31:28 Butter-Manager systemd[6644]: Butter_Manager.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Aug 28 18:31:28 Butter-Manager systemd[6644]: Butter_Manager.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/Butter_Manager/sudo: No such file or directory
Aug 28 18:31:28 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Butter_Manager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 28 18:31:28 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Butter_Manager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 28 18:31:33 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Butter_Manager.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 28 18:31:33 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Butter_Manager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 576.
Aug 28 18:31:33 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Stopped Just_Work_Pls.
Aug 28 18:31:33 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Started Just_Work_Pls.
Aug 28 18:31:33 Butter-Manager systemd[6657]: Butter_Manager.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Aug 28 18:31:33 Butter-Manager systemd[6657]: Butter_Manager.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/Butter_Manager/sudo: No such file or directory
Aug 28 18:31:33 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Butter_Manager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 28 18:31:33 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Butter_Manager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 28 18:31:33 Butter-Manager systemd[1]: Stopped Just_Work_Pls.
```

I dont know what to do after 2 days of no progress with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need sudo at all in this case, as your service is a system-wide service (it is in /lib/systemd/system), so it will run as root by default. You can simply remove the `/home/Butter_Manager/sudo` parts from your service file.

Here is why your service failed:

```
/home/Butter_Manager/sudo: No such file or directory
```

This means `/home/Butter_Manager/sudo` does not exist. Most likely `sudo` will be at `/usr/bin/sudo` or `/bin/sudo`. You can find its path by running `which sudo`. Running `realpath sudo` will simply return your current working directory + sudo (see `man realpath`). I *think* you also have this problem with the second part of your command. I *think* you mean `/bin/env /bin/python3.8` rather than `/home/Butter_Manager/env/bin/python3.8`.

Comment: When i try you path for python it gives me an error, mine tryies to open file with python, but gives me another error, that he does not see packages, while everything is installed and if i launch file manualy with sudo, everything wil work...im gived up, i dont know what to do with this ****

And yeah, your sudo path helped me, thanks...but it doesn't change my situation with "invisible" packages for systmelctl service